# What is the name of this type of tree / graph / representation?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, graphical-model, multivariable

I have come across a tree like way to organize variables and I wonder if anybody knows the name. A colleague thinks it has a "Japanese sounding name" (sorry by no mean I wish to be derogatory). So here is a quick example with a picture. Here, I want to identify the possible factors that could influence the results of a student to an exam in order to be able to study and test all the combination.

[image: Dummy tree representation]

I can't pretend this is a state of the art example. I am just very curious of how you call it and without knowing a name my researches for possibly linked keywords were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the japanese name you're looking for is Ishikawa. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishikawa_diagram

Under that name Ishikawa diagrams reflect a particular philosophy of industrial process improvement. It sounds as if you're seeing them as more generic, in which case "fishbone" or "cause and effect" diagrams might be more appropriate names.

I've seen and used such diagrams in the context of uncertainty of measurement where they can help identifying uncertainty sources, e.g. https://www.eurachem.org/index.php/publications/guides/quam where they are known as "cause and effect diagrams". The first level of branching indicates things which directly affect the outcome, then we look for things which affect the branches, then for things which affect them, and so on until it starts getting silly :-)

I'm not aware of a tool to easily and flexibly generate neat cause and effect diagrams.  Minitab has them under "Cause-and-Effect Diagram" but it is not as easy and editable as I'd like. If anyone knows of any other tool - ideally free! -  I'd appreciate a pointer.

Comment: At present this answer is very nearly link-only. Since the question is asked the way it is, I think more leeway should be given on that, but would you be able to at least give a very brief outline of the basic idea here (even a sentence or two would be a big help)?

Comment: About the space of possible combination generated, it quickly adds up! I have over 20 millions right now and it is easy to imagine that bigger projects could have a lot more!

Comment: @Doombot Your comment and "possible combination[s]" suggests you're not using the diagrams for their usual purpose - identifying causal links. Of course everything affects everything; to be useful one must restrict to non-negligible causes. If a cause has negligible effect then it's causes must also be negligible so you can stop growing that branch. E.g the Eurachem document to which I linked says "It is important to recognise that not all of the components will make a significant contribution... components that are less than one third of the largest need not be evaluated in detail".

Comment: @user20637 That's what I have been thinking... After all, I am not trying to prove something that hard to prove. I was simply overzealous when generating possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a diagram or approach ("identify the possible factors")? If the latter, this type of diagram can be created for many types of classification analyses. One is CART, Classification and Regression Trees, e.g. http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html
;multiple packages are available to create the resulting tree.